# Dynamically Create a TabControl and child Grid in a WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a wpf mvvm application using Devexpress as a third party tool. I need to create tabs dynamically that contains datagrids. I was wondering what is the best practice to do that. I already created a View contain a tab and contenttemplate as so

```
         <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns >
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" Binding="{Binding Column1}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" Binding="{Binding Column2}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 3" Binding="{Binding Column3}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

My view Model

```
  public class DataTest
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
}


public abstract class WorkspaceViewModel 
{
    public String HeaderText { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return HeaderText;
    }
    //ObservableCollection
    public ObservableCollection<DataTest> Data { get; set; }

}


public class FirstUserControlViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    public FirstUserControlViewModel()
    {
        base.HeaderText = "My First Tab";
        Data = new ObservableCollection<DataTest>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Data.Add(new DataTest()
                        {
                            Column1 = "1st Test" + i.ToString(),
                            Column2 = "1st Test" + i.ToString(),
                            Column3 = "1st Test" + i.ToString()
                        }); 
        }
    }
}


public class SecondUserControlViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    public SecondUserControlViewModel()
    {
        base.HeaderText = "My Second Tab";
        Data = new ObservableCollection<DataTest>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Data.Add(new DataTest()
            {
                Column1 = "2nd Test" + i.ToString(),
                Column2 = "2nd Test" + i.ToString(),
                Column3 = "2nd Test" + i.ToString()
            });
        }
    }
}

public class ThirdUserControlViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    public ThirdUserControlViewModel()
    {
        base.HeaderText = "My Third Tab";
        Data = new ObservableCollection<DataTest>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Data.Add(new DataTest()
            {
                Column1 = "3rd Test" + i.ToString(),
                Column2 = "3rd Test" + i.ToString(),
                Column3 = "3rd Test" + i.ToString()
            });
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{

    private ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> _workspaces;

    public ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces
    {
        get
        {
            if (_workspaces == null)
            {
                _workspaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>();
            }
            return _workspaces;
        }
    }


    public ViewModel()
    {
        Workspaces.Add(new FirstUserControlViewModel());
        Workspaces.Add(new SecondUserControlViewModel());
        Workspaces.Add(new ThirdUserControlViewModel());
    }

}
```

This is already working but I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this. Should I put the datagrid in a usercontrol and pass its parameter Data. I am also using Prism in this application is there something in their that can utilized that has a benefit?

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but only if all your Tabs are meant to display the exact same controls, with grids displaying the exact same data structures.

If you want alternative controls or data, I would recommend using implicit `DataTemplates` instead of hardcoding a `ContentTemplate`

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <!-- Draw WorkspaceAViewModel with WorkspaceAView -->
        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:WorkspaceAViewModel}">
            <local:WorkspaceAView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Draw WorkspaceBViewModel with WorkspaceBView -->
        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:WorkspaceBViewModel}">
            <local:WorkspaceBView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Draw WorkspaceCViewModel with WorkspaceCView -->
        <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:WorkspaceCViewModel}">
            <local:WorkspaceCView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

This way you can make each Workspace be any object model (perhaps with a shared interface so there is a common property to bind the Header text to), and each tab can be drawn in any way.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> _workspaces;
    public ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces
    {
        get
        {
            if (_workspaces == null)
                _workspaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>();

            return _workspaces;
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Workspaces.Add(new WorkspaceAViewModel ());
        Workspaces.Add(new WorkspaceBViewModel ());
        Workspaces.Add(new WorkspaceCViewModel ());
    }
}

public interface IWorkspace
{
    string Header { get; set; }
}

public class WorkspaceAViewModel : IWorkspace
{
    // can be anything
}

public class WorkspaceBViewModel : IWorkspace
{
    // can be anything
}

public class WorkspaceCViewModel : IWorkspace
{
    // can be anything
}
```